# ng-token-auth redirct to login page when auth:invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I'm using [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth/) and
I have below in my code:

```
$rootScope.$on('auth:invalid', function(){
  $state.go('page.login');
});
```

I do have a state `page.login` but somehow it doesn't seem to redirect. I've put in `console.log` inside the function and it seems to return text in the console so I know the event is triggered.

I also have above under module `run` action with `$state` injected into it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is this code? If is inside a controller, is the controller instantiated?

Comment: How you send the event itself? emit or broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

For handling this redirection you can use the promise returned by `validateUser()` [like this](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth/issues/103#issuecomment-125093104)

it seems that this event is not working, you can read more about it in the issue.